# pandas groupby categories with some categories grouped together

Tags: python, pandas

The title of the question is very vague, but essentially, I want to run a `groupby`  function on a pandas dataframe where I want to group by a column 'Category' with unique values of categories being `milk`,`dark`,`caramel` and `x`, `y`, `z`, etc. The column I want to perform aggregation on has the Quantity data for the number of chocolates of any kind sold. Now, I know that if `groupby('Category').sum().plot.bar()`, I will see tall bars representing high volumes for the `milk` and `dark` category and really small (if any) bars for the other 4 categories. I would like to group the other categories together such that the final plot only has 3 bars e.g. for `milk`, `dark` and `others`.
What is the easiest way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Category').sum()
df2['others'] = [x if x.name not in ['milk', 'dark'] else None for x in df2.columns]
df2[['milk', 'dark', 'others']].plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks! Instead of typing the names of each of the categories that should belong to `Others`, is there a statement that would say `everything else that is not milk and not dark?

Comment: Added a list comprehension that should grab only columns not named `milk` or `dark`.

Comment: Why do I get `invalid syntax` error with arrow pointing to `for` in the list comprehension statement? Perhaps, this should be `[xfor x in df2.columns  if x.name not in ['milk', 'dark'] ]`

Comment: Probably need an else case in that inline if.